# Numpy fft error for large vectors: "ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed" for n > 2**28

Tags: python, numpy, fft

I am trying to Fourier transform a rather large vector (up to `n = 2**30`). When this happens python crashes (I get a pop up window saying Python has stopped working). Thinking perhaps I was running out of memory (though I've got 128 GB), tried to Fourier transform slightly smaller vectors. 
It works with `n = 2**28`, takes about 210 s. However, when I try `n = 2**29` it does not work:

```
import numpy as np

N = 2**29
x = np.random.rand(N)
X = np.fft.fft(x)
```

Produces the error:

```
c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\fftpack.py in fft(a, n, axis, norm)
    190     if n is None:
    191         n = a.shape[axis]
--> 192     output = _raw_fft(a, n, axis, fftpack.cffti, fftpack.cfftf, _fft_cache)
    193     if _unitary(norm):
    194         output *= 1 / sqrt(n)

c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\fft\fftpack.py in _raw_fft(a, n, axis, init_function, work_function, fft_cache)
     63     wsave = fft_cache.pop_twiddle_factors(n)
     64     if wsave is None:
---> 65         wsave = init_function(n)
     66 
     67     if a.shape[axis] != n:

ValueError: negative dimensions are not allowed
```

What's going on here? Is numpy fft limited to `n = 2**28`?

Comment: What is your OS? Is it 32 bit or 64 bit? If 64, is your Python also 64 bit?

Comment: Windows Server 2012 Standard, 64 bit. Yes, Python is also 64 bit.

Comment: What is the actual use case? In most FFT applications you care about the spectrum. So you could take the spectrum for 4 windows of 2**28 (256 Mpts) each and look at it. Does it change?

Comment: The spectrum (Fourier magnitude) are very similar for each window.. Unfortunately I need the full complex Fourier transform, the spectral phase matters for my application.

Comment: What version of `numpy` are you working with?

Comment: Numpy version 1.14.3

Comment: I don't know the limitation of numpy here, but I'd probably write my own FFT in that case. You could look up the FFT algorithm (nice description in 'numerical recipes'). I think you should be able to use the existing results, since the algorithm (originally from Gauss) is using symmetry to go in steps of 2x points. You only have to cover two factors of two.